# How to build Rotation Output for Mesh to Points Node

Tags: geometry-nodes

Like "Distribute Points on Faces" to place this seeds on the strawberry mesh.
Instead I wanna use the "Mesh To Points" node for even distribution on the strawberry mesh.
For that I can capture the Normal Attribute, and in [Doc for Distr. Points](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/point/distribute_points_on_faces.html) the Rotation Euler can also be built from the Normal with the "Rotate Euler" Node to get the right rotation. But how exactly?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So you have two vectors. You have the *Normal*s of each vertex, and you have the axis of your *Seed* object you want to align to those normals—let's say it's the *Z* axis $[0,0,1]$. To align two 3D vectors in space, you can find a third axis that's perpendicular to both (`Cross Product`), then use that axis to rotate one of them in reverse, equal to the angle between them. You can use `Dot Product` to calculate the angle. Here's the formula ($n$: *Normal*, $z$: Z-axis):

$$cos(angle) = { dotproduct(n, z) \over length(n) \cdot length(z) } $$

Normals are already *normalized*, as in, their length is $1$, and we'll use a $1$-length *Z* value ourselves, so the divider part in that formula goes away. Which means we can get the angle simply with:

$$arccosine(dotproduct(n,z))$$

Here's an annotated setup to demonstrate, hopefully it's clear:
[image]

Maybe that's good to know. However, we already have a node that does all that for us: `Align Euler to Vector`. You can still use `Rotate Euler` afterwards, using the *Normal*s as the rotation axis, to orient them randomly, for example:

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for this explanation. Obviously I don't know enough in mathematic anymore to solve this. But this is a good explanation, now I probably can use often Dot Product and Cross Product with this in Geometry Nodes.

Comment: So already really nice explanation. But I tested it, and the rotation is still not aligned as in the Rotation Output of "Distribute Points on Faces" Node.  I can program a lil bit and saw into this [Node code](https://developer.blender.org/F14227725$91):  and its any [vector to quaternion method](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/blenlib/intern/math_rotation.c$689) with normal, obj -Z and obj +Y and then quaternion to euler, (because of the gimbal lock in Euler rotations). Maybe you can see the mathematic behind it, and make it similar.

Comment: Or then somehow rotate Euler with Normal, so every seed points downwards, to -Z

Comment: @Gordon1fm Remember the sentence from the manual you yourself had quoted: *"Keep in mind that the Z axis of the result rotation will be arbitrary, since the mesh normal used to create the rotation does not have enough information to set all three rotation axes."* It's not about quaternions, I think. Not to mention `Distribute` node uses the Face Corners to place the instances, while with `Mesh to Points` you're using the vertices, so the normals are already different. Is what you really want for them to all point "downwards/upwards"?